# WebApp (React) calls backend API fine locally but cannot call once deployed on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have my backend successfully deployed (express) on heroku, and it works fine. Further, if I launch the frontend of my application locally, it interacts properly with the deployed backend. My frontend interacts with the backend with a "fetcher.js" file, where an example function would be:

```
const getPW = async (username) => {
var res = await fetch(`http://WEBAPPBACKENDNAME.herokuapp.com/getPW?username=${username}`, {
    method: 'GET',
})
return res.json()}
```

If I deploy this frontend (separately) onto heroku, it is unable to call these functions. As a matter of fact, if I check the heroku logs for the backend, there is no trace of it even being called when I do the proper things on the frontend that should invoke the backend functions. That leads me to believe that it is not a cors error or an error with my frontend app since it runs fine locally. I doubt it's a minor error with spelling either, and am wondering if there's something unknown about Heroku frontend calling another Heroku deployed backend? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you get in the network tab of your browser devtools when making these calls from your deployed front?

Comment: Thanks for leading me here! It seems like it is calling the network, but the error seems like it's because theres a strange /undefined/ added between my api call: https://randomname.herokuapp.com/undefined/addUser/.  Locally, the undefined is not there (tested locally on Network tab as well). Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

lol it was because i was calling the link with http and not https, I guess locally it overlooks this but once delopyed this nuance is important